# Cifrar ficheiros com tamanho fixo no Arduino com o AES

Tags: linux, segurança, criptografia, arduino, aes

Sei que no arduino é complicado trabalhar com ficheiros, no entanto, como posso cifrar um ficheiro com tamanho fixo, em Kb ou em Mb no arduino usando o Aes ou outro algoritmo de cifra?

alguém tem alguma ideia??

Comment: Não sei se entendi a pergunta... Você que um arquivo de tamanho arbitrário tenha sempre o mesmo tamanho? Ou, você tem um arquivo de tamanho fixo e deseja apenas cifra-lo? Enfim. No primeiro caso você pode criar um arquivo com bytes "nulos" (0x00....00)  e usar uma cifra que seja segura contra known-plaintext.  O segundo caso não tem muito mistério, basta cifrar, [talvez isso ajude](https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/annotated.html), ele suporta ChaChaPoly, que é mais rápido que o AES, principalmente para arduino...

Comment: Pois obrigado meu, a ideia é a seguinte, tenho um ficheiro com um tamanho fixo imagina que seja de 1MB, pretendo cifra-lo e decifra-lo, usando apenas o AES no arduino, essa é a ideia principal, no entanto sei que o Arduino não lida directamente com o sistema de ficheiros do computador(e.g., Windows) . Por outra, as bibliotecas que tenho visto, lidam apenas com textos e não ficheiros...